# "Minimal upper bounds" in a categorical setting

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

It is well-known that partial orders can be seen as very simple categories (those where there is at most one morphism between every two objects).

Then, the notion of "(binary) join of two elements (i.e, the minimum of the upper bounds of these two elements)" can be understood in categorical terms; indeed it corresponds to the coproduct (and so it is a particular case of the colimit construction).

**Is there some (well-known?) categorical notion which captures, when constrained to partial orders, the notion of being a minimal element of the upper bounds of these two elements?**

I can see some reasonable ways to generalize the definition of the minimality to an (abstract) categorical setting, but either I am considering a very weak notion (i.e., with a lot of instances) or coproducts do not satisfy my property. In both cases I do not feel that the proposals I have thought are reasonable generalizations to the categorical setting.

Comment: Why don't you think coproducts satisfy your property? What *is* your property? I think more details are needed.

Comment: To be clear, are you asking for a categorical notion of a _minimal_ upper bound as opposed to a _least_ upper bound?

Comment: @Eric: I am asking for a categorical notion of "a minimal upper bound" as oposed to "the minimum upper bound". In particular, the unicity (up to isomorphism) needs to be lost.

Comment: There are notions like weak colimit or multicolimit but they're not quite the same.

Comment: A definition that seems reasonably natural that you could make is that a "minimal object" is an object $A$ such that every map to $A$ has a right inverse.  I don't think I've ever seen this notion anywhere though...

Comment: @Eric: That was one of my attempts, but in this case it happens that corproducts do not satisfy this "minimality" (if I am not worng).

Comment: @boumol: Sure they do, in the category of upper bounds.  An initial object is minimal, and if an initial object exists then every minimal object is initial.  To get the right inverse, choose the unique map, and it is a right inverse because the only map from an initial object to itself is the identity.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for a minimal upper bound (whatever that means) instead of a minimum upper bound in a general category. So you can have 2 nonisomorphic minimal objects. This means your contruction cannot be a limit (at least not in an obvious way). Also :how do you define upper bound in a general category? One way to do this is to transform your general category into a preorder (all arrows from a to b go to a single arrow) and then take your minimal upper bounds.

So express categorically , if you can, "minimal upper bound in a preorder" and then precompose it with the *thinning* functor defined above
Hth